# What happens on POST in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to follow the flow of a project.  The view has a form with a submit button.  I can see in Chrome's Network tab, that the Method is POST, and the status is Pending once I click submit (and then encounter an error caused by a bad assignment...somewhere).  I put a breakpoint in the controller on the class that handles the POST, but I'm encountering the error before I reach that breakpoint.  How do I find out what happens immediately after I click the submit button?

[Edit]
here's the error, per request
[image: kabloo-y]

Comment: Can we see the error, or "yellow page of death"?

Comment: You can try to get the debugger to stop on the exception thrown (Debug -> Exceptions -> Check CLR Thrown) and then follow the stack trace.

Comment: Split that one-code in your controller into multiple lines for better debugging.

Comment: I know why this error is being thrown.  It's because there's a variable with a value of false that I expect to be true.  However, I can't figure out what is calling this method (what is happening just before this code is hit).  @Eric, I tried setting the CLR, but the stack only shows the line the error is being thrown on.  How do I get to the step just prior?

Comment: +1 on Jason's comment. Are you able to put a breakpoint on line 61 and then see the call stack?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, is line 61 in the constructor? Perhaps the deserialization is instantiating an item request and in doing so causing this code to execute.

Comment: I FINALLY figured this out.  At POST, each of the values from the View is being cycled through, in the order the fields appear on the form.  I had failed to add the field in question (ItemRequestStatusId) as a hidden field to the form, so the value I was expecting was not being carried forward.  Once I added the hidden field, I saw the value I was expecting at the point in the code I posted above, and also saw the result I expected to see (and the error went away as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY figured this out. At POST, each of the values from the View is being cycled through, in the order the fields appear on the form. I had failed to add the field in question (ItemRequestStatusId) as a hidden field to the form, so the value I was expecting was not being carried forward. Once I added the hidden field, I saw the value I was expecting at the point in the code I posted above, and also saw the result I expected to see (and the error went away as well).